# Do I put index.html file in build folder

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, webpack

I'm building my React/Node app on Heroku by running `webpack -p` with `heroku-postbuild`.

I have a build folder which webpack adds the `bundle.js` to and the whole app is served using Express with:

```
//Serve React App
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/build/" + "index.html" );
});
```

However, I'm not sure where to place my `index.html`? Typically, I've always kept it inside the build folder but I'm having to re-think this approach as I don't wan't to include the build folder in version control.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can put index.html in `app` and add some task runner to put it in `build` folder. Or, you can use https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin